# Does Nagilum have unlimited powers?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

Is Nagilum (from the episode [*Where Silence has Lease*](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Where_Silence_Has_Lease_(episode))) omnipotent and omnipresent? He's not omniscient as he is doing an experiment to learn more about humans.

He seems omnipotent as he can conjure up any reality (though it is not clear if this requires the expense of limited resources). He seems omnipresent, or at least have the ability to transport anywhere. Even when the Enterprise was out of the void Nagilum communicated to Picard on a computer.

EDIT: after reading Stefan's answer I wondered, can one be omnipotent without being omniscient? If someone was omnipotent wouldn't they be able to use there "powers to do anything" to make the experiment to satisfy their quest for knowledge? If they had a limited capacity to learn or recall knowledge couldn't they use their power to do anything to remove this barrier?

Comment: A holo deck and a communications array could do the same

Comment: Can he make a rock so big even he can't lift it?

Comment: If he was omnipresent he would have witnessed billions of people mating and dying and would have no need to experiment. If he was omnipotent, he could make Picard want to stay and be subject to experiments, he could deactivate the selfdestruct - sequence or he could bring the enterprise back once Picard and Riker stopped it. My guess would be: Neither omnipotent nor omnipresent

Comment: @TomJNowell what do you mean? Lot's of people have holo decks and communication arrays but they aren't able to do the same things as Nagilum. Are you saying that Nagilum some how is able to do it in an arbitrary region of space where as holograms are confined to the holo deck?

Comment: Any time you use the words omnipotent, omnipresent you presume the being can look through all of space and time and nothing is beyond their ability to do, which Nagilum was clearly neither. He had to experiment to know, thus not omniscient and he could not force compliance therefore not omnipotent...

Comment: @Thaddeus "He had to experiment to know, thus not omnipresent" did you mean "omniscient" instead of "omnipresent"?

Comment: @Celiritas I think in this case omnipotence and omnipresence are largely synonymous. If it can see everything everywhere it also knows pretty much everything (excepting categories such as thoughts and future events, of course). The behaviour it's trying to examine would be already known to it if it was omnipresent.

Comment: Though I'd be inclined to answer "no" to any questions of beings of infinite powers. It's a major theme of TNG that nothing is truly "God-like", just evolved and/or living in a higher state of existence than us. Limited power in their own scope, but from our perspective all-powerful. Very important difference to keep in mind.

Comment: @DavidS - The Q are repeatedly described as possessing "godlike" powers.

Comment: One thing I'm really curious about still is "where" Nagilum is. Even after the Enterprise left the illusion (at the end of the episode) he communicates with them (or at least appears on a computer screen). Given this discussion he isn't omnipresent, but perhaps close...

Comment: @Richard God-like powers, but not God-like beings. Q at some point mentions humanity could attain the same state as the Q, which to me stops them being God-like. But I should't really have made that last comment since I'm sure we could have entire threads over the definition(s) of God-like anyway :P

Comment: "can one be omnipotent without being omniscient" - IMHO, no.  If you were omniscient would be a subset of omnipotent.  If I can do anything, then I can choose to be everywhere at once and know everything at once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not much information if available about him but from the way he acts we can deduce:

He is not omnipotent as he had to try to trick Picard into turning off the self destruct rather than just switching it off himself.

He is not omnipresent as he asked for a demonstration of reproduction.  If he was omnipresent he would have been in various bedrooms, film studios etc where he would have already witnessed this.